# How to renaming a lot of folders with a Windows batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-rename, batch-rename

I need change a lot of folders with a batch script file..

I have those format of name folders:

- 2013.03.12.08.05.06_Debug_Test1
- 2013.03.12.08.04.09_Debug_Test2
- ...

I need change for this:

- 2013.12.03.08.05.06_Debug_Test1
- 2013.12.03.08.04.09_Debug_Test2

Invert the number 12 with the number 03

This is possible using a windows batch file?

Comment: checkout [renamer](http://github.com/75lb/renamer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=1,2,3*delims=." %%a in ('dir /b /ad "*.*.*.*") do if not %%b==%%c echo ren "%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d" "%%a-%%c.%%b.%%d"
for /f "tokens=1,2,3*delims=.-" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "*-*.*.*") do if not %%b==%%c echo ren "%%a-%%b.%%c.%%d" "%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d"
```

Should get you started.

The first `FOR` selects directories of the format `*.*.*.*` and renames them `*-*.*.*` with the 2nd and 3rd elements swapped.

The second renames the renamed directories to change the `-` to `.`

Consider directories `2013.03.12.08.05.06_Debug_Test1` and `2013.12.03.08.05.06_Debug_Test1` - attempting to rename the one will fail because the other exists, hence need to rename twice.

(I've assumed that '-' does not exist in your directorynames - you may wish to substitute some other character - `#`,`@`,`$`,`q` suggest themselves)

Note that I've simply `ECHO`ed the rename. Since the second rename depends on the first, the second set wouldn't be produced until the `echo` is removed from the first after careful checking.

I'd suggest you create a sample subdirectory to test first, including such names as I've highlighted.

Comment: Great Magoo you are a genius!

Comment: `dir *.*.*.*` is no different than `dir *`. You will need to pipe the result to a FINDSTR regex if you want to properly filter the folders. Good catch with the 2 step process, but it can be simplified. In the first FOR loop use `ren "%%a.%%b.%%c.%%d" "%%a.%%c.%%b.%%d.rename"`and then the entire 2nd FOR loop can be replaced by a simple `ren *.rename *.`

Answer (score 1):

Using [StringSolver](https://github.com/MikaelMayer/StringSolver), which requires a valid JRE installation and sbt, allows to use a semi-automatic version of move:

```
move 2013.03.12.08.05.06_Debug_Test1 2013.12.03.08.05.06_Debug_Test1
```

Then check the transformation:

```
move --explain

concatenates for all a>=0 (a 2-digit number from the substring starting at the a+1-th number ending at the end of the a+1-th AlphaNumeric token in first input + the substring starting at the 2*a+2-th token not containing 0-9a-zA-Z ending at the end of the a+3-th non-number in first input) + the first input starting at the 4th AlphaNumeric token.
```

which means that it decomposed the transformation by:

```
2013.12.03.08.05.06_Debug_Test1
AAAABBBBAABCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
where
A is "a 2-digit number from the substring starting at the a+1-th number ending at the end of the a+1-th AlphaNumeric token in first input"
B is "the substring starting at the 2*a+2-th token not containing 0-9a-zA-Z ending at the end of the a+3-th non-number in first input"
C is "the first input starting at the 4th AlphaNumeric token."
```

which corresponds to what you expected for folders of this type.

If you do not trust it, you can have a dry run:

```
move --test
```

which displays what the mapping would do on all folders.

Then perform the transformation for all folders using `move --auto` or the abbreviated command

```
move
```

### Alternative

Using the `Monitor.ps1` modified and run in `Powershell -Sta`, you can do it yourself in Windows like in this [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rbhAv3uBFqw).

DISCLAIMER: I am a co-author of this software developped for academic purposes.

Comment: How did the test go? Was it easy to install?